# In C, convert 2 doubles to form one character string

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf

I have these two variables in `C`:

```
double predict_label = 6.0;
double prob_estimates = 8.0;
```

How do I convert these two variables in `C` to `char` and print out a string that says something like "The value for predict label is 6 and the value for probability estimates is 8."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you want to *convert to char* so much as you want to *print the integer values of*.  Assuming that, this should suffice:

```
printf("predict label is %d and probability estimates is %d\n",
       (int)predict_label, (int)prob_estimates);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use snprintf() if you actually want to add the variable values to a string:

```
#define BUF_LEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char str[BUF_LEN];
    double predict_label = 6.0;
    double prob_estimates = 8.0;

    snprintf(str, BUF_LEN, "The value for predict label is %d and the value for probability estimates is %d.",
        (int)predict_label, (int)prob_estimates);

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the purpose of using a  buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange to print the floating point values with no decimal places (and hence no decimal point) into a string variable that can then be printed to files however you wish — using [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) for example.  The code also uses string concatenation to avoid overly long lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double predict_label = 6.0;
    double prob_estimates = 8.0;
    char buffer[256];

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
             "The value for predict label is %.0f"
             " and the value for probability estimates is %.0f.",
             predict_label, prob_estimates);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the purpose of using a  buffer?

Comment: The question mentions converting to a string, more or less. It isn’t clear on what’s required.  This is one way to do it; writing directly is another. It depends on the context.